# SSRS Dropdown on reports keeps defaulting to value When no Default Value is chosen

Tags: reporting-services

Im a using SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Server version 12.06164.21) on a SQL Server 2014.

Using VS 2019 to create and deploy the reports.

I have a report that is using a dropdown which on the Report Paramaters gets it values from a query.
When developing I set a default value.
After developing is complete I then set the Default Values to 'No Default Values'.
Preview mode in VS2019 looks ok.

I then deploy to the server.

BUT...
The report on the Report Server browser still defaults to this value and also there is no '' option in the dropdown. ?!
This has also happened on anothe rsimilar report.
The above occurs on other users' machines and on different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Once a report is deployed, the default parameter values do not get updated when you redeploy the same report again.

Two ways to fix this.

1. Delete the report from the server and redeploy, this will set the default parameters to whatever they are set to in VS
2. Navigate to the report via the web portal, right-click the report and choose "Manage" then edit or remove the defaults in the parameters section.

Comment: Thanks, yes just realized this after posting.  You are quite correct